# Angular CLI failed to compile after adding @types

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Angular CLI failed to compile after adding @types using the following command

```
npm install @types/jquery @types/bootbox bootstrap jquery --save
```

I am getting following error while trying to transpile/compile the code

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to upgrade typescript

Comment: I am using Version 2.4.1 now

Comment: so then downgrading :)

Comment: but before worth to check in `@types/jquery/package.json` for typescript version dependency